# Can I run an online forum on Ethereum

Tags: dapp-development

This question is related to my previous question: can I run an online forum on Ethereum, or a stand of free books on a given topic? Could these be considered blockapps? Thanks.

Comment: The blockapps tag is about the company and the tag description has been updated. The tag has been removed from this question since it isn't applicable